# SQL Server Allowing Login on providing wrong PORT Number

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ssms

I am facing a problem in `SSMS`.
There are two `SQL Instance` running on same system.

```
 1. localhost\sql2008,1434
 2. localhost\Personal,1433
```

I kept `Second Instance` to run on Default port i.e. `1433` and `First Instance` to new port as `1434`.

Both Instance has Databases which are same in name, but with difference in Data.

Now problem:

In `SSMS` when `Connect Server` Prompt comes and when I Enter

`Server Name =` **`localhost\Personal,1434`** then

It Actually Login to **`localhost\sql2008,1434`** service.
And similarly, when I Enter

`Server Name =` **`localhost\sql2008,1433`** then

It Actually Login to **`localhost\personal,1433`** service.

Why it is so?

Is it a bug of `SSMS`?

According to Me, this should not allow me to Login, since there is no such instance with provided name is running on mentioned port.

Please provide some solution.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance name in the connection string is not authoritative. It is used to determine the port number, or the named pipe name, using the [SQL Browser service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165724%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (which normally takes UDP 1434, but that is a different story). If you provide the port number explicitly in the connection string then the instance name is not used for anything, the client attempts to connect to the provided hostname (`localhost`) and port. Authorization succeed, so the connection succeeds. You could write anything in the instance name, `localhost\foobar,1433` will also connect successfully.

Comment: Thank You very much. As you mentioned when **Port No.** is provided it don't see **Instance Name**, just checks URL i.e. **localhost** in my case and trying to connect. A New thing and very Interesting one I learned today.